# My aspnet Website Database Isn't Connecting Right

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core

I am having problems finding the proper way to the data to and from my database. I have set it up to pass the variables I believed I needed but have gotten mixed results.

I tried, setting the default "add" value to a null element, which resulted in the table not accepting anything at all, then I tried changing it to a default value, where it only accept THAT value. afterwords, I created a global variable to pass my input variable too, but now the user has to input the value twice before the database accepts it and the website displays it.

html:

```
    @page "/"
@using FireData.Data.Extra;
@using FireData.Data

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

@code
{
    List<FireTest> Numbers = new List<FireTest>();

}
@inherits OwningComponentBase<FireDataService>
<h1>Vehicle Entry</h1>
<p>
    <!-- Add a new vehicles -->
    <button class="btn btn-success"
            @onclick="AddNewVehicle">
        Add New Vehicle
    </button>
</p>

    @if (ShowPopup)
{
    <!-- This is the popup to create or edit a vehicle -->
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" style="display:block" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Edit Forecast</h3>
                    <!-- Button to close the popup -->
                    <button type="button" class="close"
                            @onclick="ClosePopup">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">X</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!-- Edit form for the current vehicle -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                           placeholder="Enter New Vehicle"
                           @bind="objVehicleNumber.VehicleNumber" />
                    <br />
                    <!-- Button to save the Vehicle -->
                    <button class="btn btn-success"
                            @onclick="SaveVehicle">
                        Save
                    </button>&nbsp;

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

        @if (Numbers == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Vehicles</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var Data in Numbers)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Data.VehicleNumber</td>
                    <td>
                        <!-- Edit the current Vehicle -->
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"
                                @onclick="(() => EditVehicle(Data))">
                            Edit
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

}
```

```
//front end
@inject FireDataService FireDataSvc
@code {
    String x = "";
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Numbers = await FireDataSvc.GetIDAsync("0000000");
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    FireTest objVehicleNumber = new FireTest();
    bool ShowPopup = false;
    void ClosePopup()
    {
        // Close the Popup
        ShowPopup = false;
    }
    void AddNewVehicle()
    {
        // enter new Vehicle
        x = objVehicleNumber.VehicleNumber;
        objVehicleNumber = new FireTest();
        // Set Id to null so we know it is a new record
        objVehicleNumber.VehicleNumber = x;
        // Open the Popup
        ShowPopup = true;
       
    }

    //save method
    async Task SaveVehicle()
    {
        // Close the Popup
        ShowPopup = false;
        // x should reflect the user input
        if (objVehicleNumber.VehicleNumber == x)
        {
            // Create new vehicle
            FireTest objNewVehicleNumber = new FireTest();
            objNewVehicleNumber.VehicleNumber = objVehicleNumber.VehicleNumber;

            // Save the result
            var result =
            @Service.CreateVehicleAsync(objNewVehicleNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            var result =
            @Service.UpdateVehicleAsync(objVehicleNumber);
            
        }

        // Get the vehicle for the current session
        Numbers = await @Service.GetIDAsync(x);
    }
```

```
//back end
    public class FireDataService
 {
     private readonly InformationContext _context;
     public FireDataService(InformationContext context)
     {
         _context = context;
     }
     public async Task<List<FireTest>>
         GetIDAsync(string strCurrentUser)
     {

         return await _context.FireTests.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
     }


     //create method
     public Task<FireTest>
 CreateVehicleAsync(FireTest objFireData)
     {
         _context.FireTests.Add(objFireData);
         _context.SaveChanges();
         return Task.FromResult(objFireData);
     }
```

In a similar fashion the option I have created for users to edit their inputs doesn't properly change the result of their input, only changing it for a brief instant before reverting back to the original value, I have tried playing around with my backend update method, as I believe the issue is caused from their but have received no results of note that or using break pointing.

```
    {
        // front end
        objVehicleNumber = fireTest;
        ShowPopup = true;
    }
```

```
//back end
UpdateVehicleAsync(FireTest objFireData)
        {
            var ExistingVehicle =
                _context.FireTests
                .Where(x => x.VehicleNumber == objFireData.VehicleNumber)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (ExistingVehicle != null)
            {
                ExistingVehicle.VehicleNumber = objFireData.VehicleNumber;
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                return Task.FromResult(false);
            }
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
```

Comment: Your use of the `x` variable is confusing. If `x` is supposed to be null I don't see why. `// A new vehicle will have the Id set to null if (objVehicleNumber.VehicleNumber == x)` You should test for `null` by testing for `null` -- `(if x == null)` or `(if x is null)`

Comment: sorry, left my comment in there by mistake indicating that it was originally set to null which I indicated i my explanation above. 'x' catches the user input to make the value more dynamic.

Comment: Async methods should be `awaited`. You have missed `await` when calling  `CreateVehicleAsync` and `UpdateVehicleAsync`. And do not mix async methods with synchronous versions.

Comment: you mean like this: ```var result = await @Service.CreateVehicleAsync(objNewVehicleNumber);```? I figured it didn't matter nuch because the IDAsynce is the core of the function, but I gave it a try anyway and am still getting the same result.  Just incase, I also changed my global variable 'x' back to null as well.

Comment: Your `SaveVehicle` is still confusing. Why do you create a new FireTest when `objVehicleNumber.VehicleNumber == x`? Its not clear what your logic is for "saving/creating" vs "saving/updating". Now you have hardcoded `x` as an empty string. Just write `if string.IsNullOrEmpty(objVehicleNumber.VehicleNumber)` and spare us from trying to figure out what `x` is.

Comment: I think this comment is off topic, but tldr this is a matter of semantics. I am saving a NEW vehicle which in MY eyes is the same things as creating one. Literally all 'x' is, is a global variable made to help pass user inputs easier, it was originally an empty set but I was getting no results from it, I thought I made this clear in my post.

Comment: and setting it to your above recommended code only results in the exact same problem I had when I had it set == to null. as in, it results in no changes to the database whatsoever and edit still doesn't work either

Comment: You need to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is not clear from your code how you are getting the results you are describing - as I said, your code is confusing. Even your question title is confusing - you say the database isn't connecting but then you also say it works if you input a value twice (which suggests the connection does work). You really just aren't making a lot of sense. We are trying to piece it together from the clues in your code but you aren't making it easy on us.

Comment: I have given you every bit of code that is related to the issue. all you are missing is the html that lays out the page and some auto generated back end stuff that manages encryption.
I have tried to be as specific as possible, the problem is that the user inputs are not connecting properly to the database, but after creating the global variable which confuses you for some reason it now accepts it after inputting the same value twice. and the inputs to the edit method get rejected completely after initially displaying the value for a brief second. I tried to make this clear as possible.

Comment: Yes we need to see the inputs, which means the html that is laying out the page and would show how you are calling these methods and supplying these inputs.

Comment: i've added it to the main post. but it's nothing complex.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem (I tried for a long time). The problem you are describing (data appearing briefly then disappearing) does not sound like a database connection problem. I suggest you use a mock data source to eliminate the data connection variable from this equation and see how your program works. If it works with a mock data source (an in memory list or something like that), then add back in the database and chalk it up to experience - but you may learn something in the process. Also I'd focus on one thing in this question - add new, or update, not both (focus).

Comment: Note that you may be experience problems with EF I'm not sure it seems like there's "something wrong" with the way you update but 1) that shouldn't affect the create new, and 2) that wouldn't cause data to appear then disappear. So, there could be more than one thing that needs fixing at the same time here, which complicates matters (hence my suggestion - remove the database from the equation).